# Why am I receiving "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sapb1

I am wanting to total the days in the query for [# of orders] & [total revenue] when I run this query.  But I am receiving this error in my sql server "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

My code is this:

```
select  TaxDate [Date]
        ,count(docentry) [# of Orders]
        ,sum(doctotal)-(SUM(TotalExpns)+SUM(VatSum)) [$]

from ORDR

where   CANCELED<>'Y'
        and SlpCode = '37'
        and TaxDate >= '2015-05-26'
        and DocStatus = 'C'

GROUP BY TaxDate

UNION ALL

select  'Total'
        ,SUM(docentry)
        ,sum(doctotal)-(SUM(TotalExpns)+SUM(VatSum))

from ORDR

where   CANCELED<>'Y'
        and SlpCode = '37'
        and TaxDate >= '2015-05-26'
        and DocStatus = 'C'

group by TaxDate
order by TaxDate
```

I am very new to writing queries.  I have no experience with using the "UNION" tool.  So I appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `union all` with a date in the first subquery and `'Total'` in the second.  SQL Server decides that both should be dates, so you are getting a conversion error on `'Total'`.

They need to be the same type.  Try changing the first to something like:

```
select convert(varchar(10), TaxDate, 121) as [Date],
       count(docentry) [# of Orders],
       sum(doctotal)-(SUM(TotalExpns)+SUM(VatSum)) [$]
```

You don't need a `union all` for this query anyway.  I think `with rollup` does what you want:

```
select  TaxDate [Date], count(docentry) [# of Orders],
        sum(doctotal)-(SUM(TotalExpns)+SUM(VatSum)) [$]
from ORDR
where CANCELED <> 'Y' and SlpCode = '37' and TaxDate >= '2015-05-26' and
      DocStatus = 'C'
group by TaxDate with rollup;
```

Comment: Gordon, that "With rollup" feature was super awesome! Can I use that in the `GROUP` statement on queries where I want totals at the end of the columns?

Comment: @KTate . . . `rollup` adds a new row with the summarize.  I'm not sure what a total is "at the end of the columns".  If you want a column with the total, then you need to do the arithmetic.

Comment: I meant that in the sense what `rollup` was accomplishing by totaling my 2 arthimitic columns. When you say "you need to do the arithmetic" what would be an example of doing that for a column?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in your second query of the `UNION`, your first column is explicitly a `VARCHAR`, but in your first one, it is a `DATE`.  These datatypes need to match.

I would suggest doing the following:

```
select  Cast(TaxDate As Varchar (10)) [Date]
        ,count(docentry) [# of Orders]
        ,sum(doctotal)-(SUM(TotalExpns)+SUM(VatSum)) [$]

from ORDR

where   CANCELED<>'Y'
        and SlpCode = '37'
        and TaxDate >= '2015-05-26'
        and DocStatus = 'C'

GROUP BY TaxDate

UNION ALL

select  'Total'
        ,SUM(docentry)
        ,sum(doctotal)-(SUM(TotalExpns)+SUM(VatSum))

from ORDR

where   CANCELED<>'Y'
        and SlpCode = '37'
        and TaxDate >= '2015-05-26'
        and DocStatus = 'C'

group by TaxDate
order by [Date]
```

Comment: Hey Siyual, thanks so much for the help. When I entered your code into my server I received this message: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.`

Comment: @KTate Sorry, I didn't look that far down the query - I've updated the `Order By` clause.

Comment: Just entered the updated code and am still getting the same error message that I sent in my previous comment.